# Running bash script does not return to terminal when using ampersand (&) to run a subprocess in the background

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, background-process, ampersand

I have a script (lets call it parent.sh) that makes 2 calls to a second script (child.sh) that runs a java process. The child.sh scripts are run in the background by placing an & at the end of the line in parent.sh. However, when i run parent.sh, i need to press Ctrl+C to return to the terminal screen. What is the reason for this? Is it something to do with the fact that the child.sh processes are running under the parent.sh process. So the parent.sh doesn't die until the childs do?

parent.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
child.sh param1a param2a &
child.sh param1b param2b &
exit 0
```

child.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
java com.test.Main 
echo "Main Process Stopped" | mail -s "WARNING-Main Process is down." user@email.com
```

As you can see, I don't want to run the java process in the background because i want to send a mail out when the process dies. Doing it as above works fine from a functional standpoint, but i would like to know how i can get it to return to the terminal after executing parent.sh.

Comment: Does it need to be ctrl-c or does hitting enter get you a prompt too? What does `ps` say is running at the point where you hit ctrl-c?

Comment: Is the java program expecting any input? Does it help if you change it to `java com.test.Main < /dev/null`?

Comment: @ arco, the java program does take input, so that is not an option @Etan - it must be Ctrl C, ps says the 2 java processes are running and parent.sh

Comment: Add a `> /dev/null` at the end of the line with `mail`. `mail` will otherwise try to start its interactive mode.

Comment: @theGuardian, if it takes input, how do you expect it to background itself? It necessarily has a controlling terminal handle.

Comment: Does pressing enter also display your prompt when this happens, or is it only ctrl+c?

Comment: As @CharlesDuffy says, if the script takes input how can it run in the background? Where is it going to get its input from? You aren't supplying it any (and you kill it with ctrl-c, I'd expect you to have to hit it twice actually).

Comment: The usual answer for this (if you *must* read input from the terminal before daemonizing, rather than getting that input via the command line or environment) is to have it first read its input then self-daemonize, which involves closing all its handles on the terminal (replacing stdin, stdout and stderr with handles on `/dev/null`), calling setsid() to create a new session, and doing a double fork.

Answer (score 10):

What i ended up doing was to make to change parent.sh to the following

```
#!/bin/bash
child.sh param1a param2a > startup.log &
child.sh param1b param2b > startup2.log &
exit 0
```

I would not have come to this solution without your suggestions and root cause analysis of the issue. Thanks!

And apologies for my inaccurate comment. (There was no input, I answered from memory and I remembered incorrectly.)

Comment: I experienced the same problem and this worked for me. Replacing `&` with `> /dev/null &` also works if you don't need to collect the output.

Answer (score 8):

The following link from the [Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) suggests adding a `wait` after your `mail` command in `child.sh`:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html

### Summary of the above document

> Within a script, running a command in the background with an ampersand (&)
>   may cause the script to hang until ENTER is hit. This seems to occur with
>   commands that write to stdout. It can be a major annoyance.
>
> ....
>   ....
>
> As Walter Brameld IV explains it:
>
> As far as I can tell, such scripts don't actually hang. It just
>   seems that they do because the background command writes text to
>   the console after the prompt. The user gets the impression that
>   the prompt was never displayed. Here's the sequence of events:
>
> 1. Script launches background command.
> 2. Script exits.
> 3. Shell displays the prompt.
> 4. Background command continues running and writing text to the
>      console.
> 5. Background command finishes.
> 6. User doesn't see a prompt at the bottom of the output, thinks script
>      is hanging.

If you change `child.sh` to look like the following you shouldn't experience this annoyance:

```
#!/bin/bash
java com.test.Main
echo "Main Process Stopped" | mail -s "WARNING-Main Process is down." user@gmail.com
wait
```

Or as @SebastianStigler states in a comment to your question above:

> Add a `> /dev/null` at the end of the line with mail. mail will otherwise try to start its interactive mode.

This will cause the mail command to write to `/dev/null` rather than `stdout` which should also stop this annoyance.

Hope this helps

Comment: OP can also add the `wait` command after the last call to `child.sh` (right before `exit 0` and the effect will be the same.

Answer (score 8):

The process was still linked to the controlling terminal because **`STDOUT` needs somewhere to go**.  You solved that problem by redirecting to a file ( `> startup.log` ).

If you're not interested in the output, discard STDOUT completely ( `>/dev/null` ).

If you're not interested in errors, either, discard both ( `&>/dev/null` ).

If you want the processes to keep running even after you log out of your terminal, use **nohup** — that effectively disconnects them from what you are doing and leaves them to quietly run in the background until you reboot your machine (or otherwise kill them).

```
nohup child.sh param1a param2a &>/dev/null &
```