# Why does this nested bash command with subshells hang?

Tags: bash

In Bash 5.0.3, I'm running the following command and I'm curious why the output spawns an additional shell after the first one completes?

```sh
( ( ( sleep 1 ) && echo "done sleeping for one second" & ) || \
( ( sleep 0.5 ) && echo "done sleeping for half second" & ) ) && echo $?
```

By spawn an additional shell, I mean the terminal itself returns the prompt to the user and interrupts it once again:

```
user@system $ ( ( ( sleep 1 ) && echo "done sleeping for one second" & ) || ( ( sleep 0.5 ) && echo "done sleeping for half second" & ) ) && echo $?
0
user@system $ done sleeping for one second
^C
user@system $
```

Comment: `I mean the terminal itself returns the prompt to the user and interrupts it once again` - I do not understand that. There is no "additional shell" - which part of the output is exactly not clear to you? Which part exactly of the output you interpret as "additional shell"? Well, the command spawns a background process, that waits 1 second and then prints something, so the background process is going to finish a 1 second after the foreground `echo $?` finishes.

Comment: This is an entirely cosmetic effect explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28282164/1899640). You'll find that `ls<enter>` still works exactly as expected, even though the screen is slightly garbled from the asynchronous output

Comment: you kicked off a process in the background ... said (background) process generates output ... where do you think that (background process) output is going to show up?

Comment: I think no reference provided fully explains what is happening. A crucial point to understand is that running a subshell in background with `( command & )` immediately returns 0, so `echo $?` outputs immediately.